# How to enable scrolling functionality to linear layout in android?

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout

Can anyone help me how to enable scrolling functionality for linearlayout?

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance, \n Sathish.", don't do it next time

Answer (score 14):

Use a ScrollView ?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="110px">
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how can i do this without using a scrollview inside the linearlayout?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want a ScrollView?

Comment: scrollview is what you're looking for. It can only contain one child layout and the scroll bar on the side can be removed in one of the xml attributes if you want.

Comment: I need to make a linear layout scrollable without using a Scrollview because I have a grid view inside the linear layout which doesn't scroll properly if it is inside a scrollview. Is there a way?

Comment: scollview can have only one item in it

Comment: why is this answer states as a question?

Answer (score 11):

You can put anything inside a scroll view to make something (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and etc) scrollable. You can follow http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Place your contents inside scrollview

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollViewID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <!-- your content --->
  </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content inside a ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

scrollview can have only one item in it..
so to enable your functionality ,you have to put linear layout(generally..) and
add custom views or layouts as a child to the linear layout..

I advice you to use listview and ArrayLists to generate a scrollable list

Answer (score 0):

scroll view will take only one direct child under it.you can use this code as a sample.hope this will help you.

```
<TableLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/syncservice_url" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   <TextView android:text="Settings" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="6pt" android:typeface="serif"/>
<View android:background="@color/Black" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

        <TextView android:text="Multimedia file list Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/multimediafileListUrl"  android:layout_height="40dip"></EditText>



        <TextView android:text="Multimedia Download Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/MultiMediaDownloadUrl"  android:layout_height="40dip"></EditText>



        <TextView android:text="Reports Upload Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/ReportUploadUrl"  android:layout_height="40dip"></EditText>



        <TextView android:text="Presentation Timimg Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/PresentationTimeUrl"  android:layout_height="40dip"></EditText>


</TableLayout><!-- sync scrvice closed -->

   <TableLayout android:id="@+id/report_url" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:text="Reporting " android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="6pt" android:typeface="serif"/>
    <View android:background="@color/Black" android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>


        <TextView android:text="Report Submit Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/ReportSubmitUrl"  android:layout_height="40dip"></EditText>



        <TextView android:text="Appointment List Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<EditText android:gravity="left" android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
                    android:cursorVisible="false" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip" android:id="@+id/AppointMentListUrl" />

  </TableLayout><!-- sync Report closed -->
   <TableLayout android:id="@+id/Locationmap_url" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <TextView android:text="IMEI Post Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/IMeiPostUrl" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>



        <TextView android:text="Kml Download Url" android:textColor="@color/Black" android:textSize="5pt" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/kmldownloadurl"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

    <Button android:text="Save" android:id="@+id/SettingSave" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>     
</TableLayout><!--Locationmap closed -->

</TableLayout><!-- main table layout -->
 </TableLayout><!-- main table layout -->

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ScrollView , provide him width and length then use any layout or view and provide them their width and height .